# ng-sortable not functioning as per documentation

Tags: angularjs

ngSortable module doesn't seem to be functioning.

It's included in the template as:

```
<ul as-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="items">
      <li ng-repeat="item in subsections" as-sortable-item>
        <div data-as-sortable-item-handle>{{item.name}}</div>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

While in the controller:

```
$scope.subsections = [{
    name: 'one'
  }, {
    name: 'Two'
  }];

  $scope.sortableOptions = {
    orderChanged: function(event) {
      console.log('orderChanged');
    },
    itemMoved: function(event) {
      console.log('Item Moved');
    }

  };
```

Plnkr available here:
http://plnkr.co/edit/m4rrhlPM47netEwdfjc7

I am following the docs here:
https://github.com/a5hik/ng-sortable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration is good, but the trick is in ng-model.

Instead of `ng-model="items"`, you have to put the arrayList in ng-model, in your case `ng-model="subsections"`.

The final HTML look will be:

```
 <ul as-sortable="sortableOptions" ng-model="subsections">
  <li ng-repeat="item in subsections" as-sortable-item>
    <div data-as-sortable-item-handle>{{item.name}}</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Here is the [plunker version.](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hoo6MmWF28IeTnBrdAIT?p=preview)